# using describe function in pandas

Tags: python, pandas, csv

I have successfully used the describe method in python to output the count, mean, etc. of a given column.

```
def open_housing():
    path_to_file = (r'C:\Users\ablev\OneDrive\Desktop\SDEV 300 6384 Build'
                    r'ing Secure Python Programs\Week 5\Housing.csv')
    data = pd.read_csv(path_to_file, encoding=('utf-8'))
    evaluate_data = data['AGE'].describe()
    return evaluate_data


print(open_housing())
```

These are the results:

```
count    10042.000000
mean        47.219478
std         23.149799
min         -9.000000
25%         34.000000
50%         49.000000
75%         63.000000
max         93.000000
Name: AGE, dtype: float64
```

Is there a way to not print the 25%,50%,75% and also get rid of the last line Name: AGE, dtype: float64? Thanks! The csv file can be found here: [CSV Housing file](https://github.com/guywithamustache/webfiles/blob/main/Housing.csv)

Comment: `data['AGE'].describe()` returns a series (like a column by itself). What's being printed at the bottom describes the series' name and data type.

Comment: `print(open_housing().drop(['25%', '50%', '75%']).to_string()) ` etc

Comment: Thank You very much. Is there a reason you appended the .drop to the function open_housing() I can append it to when I get the .describe method as well, is this correct? Also, would you know how to get rid of the series name and data type from the output or am I stuck with it?

Comment: If I could ask one more question, do you know how I would get rid of all the leading zeros that it prints out from the data set. Instead of 63.00000 just 63 etc? Thank you!